# slicing insert question, L[1:1]

Tags: python, slice

practising some python, which is a pretty easy language to grab up.

I have

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4]
>>> L[1:1] = [1,2,3]
>>> L
[1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

so on line two actually `L[1:1]` is empty list, but how can python understand that insert the `[1,2,3]` list to starting from `1`. I guess there is some internals which is not transparent to us, here apparently, I guess `L[1:1]` returns a reference to index `1` even if that returns an empty list...

Best wishes,
Umut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L[1:1]` means the slice of the list `L` starting at index 1 (the second element), up to but not including index 1.  So it is an empty list.  On the right-hand side of an assignment, it is simply an anonymous empty list.  But on the left-hand side, the assignment knows where the slice has been made, and can splice in the new list value into the proper place.

Answer (score 3):

Slicing behaves differently depending on whether it's on the left- or right-hand side of an expression. When it's on the left side, it doesn't return a list - instead, it behaves as a slice object, which knows more about slices and has assignment specifically overridden to operate as insertion.

Answer (score 2):

The official Python Tutorial explains it best, in my opinion. The end of [Chapter 3.1.2](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) has the following diagram:

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | H | e | l | p | A |
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5
```

What this illustrates is that you can think of the indices as pointing BETWEEN the elements. So in this illustration, if specifying a slice `[1:1]`, you are actually referring to the space between `H` and `e`, but not including them.

If you wanted to overwrite `H` and `e`, you would specify the slice `[0:2]`.